# svm.predict cannot predict new dataset

Tags: r, svm, predict

the data set is rather simple, 
[image: screenshot]

I was trying to see what the prediction of the result would be if i consider     result1 as a numeric variable.

so I subsetted the dataset into two part, one for training and the other one for testing randomly, run the svm code, and predict the testing set

```
wh.train = wh[1:1106,]
wh.test = wh[1107:1120,]
model1 = svm(result1 ~., wh.train)
pred1 = predict(model1, wh.test)
```

then result come out to me is really weird,
    named numeric(0)

Comment: Impossible to say without looking at your data. I'd suggest checking the wh.test object to make sure there are no issues with it.

Comment: @Phil The thing is, if i just run predict(model1), it works totally fine. The testing dataset is exactly same as the training set.

Comment: Running `predict(model1)` will fit the model on the data it's been trained on. If that works, than the issue isn't with the `model1` object. I think the issue is that there's something wrong with the `wh.test` object. If you just call up the object, do you see anything unusual?

Comment: it looks normal. The testing dataset were just 10 data randomly pick from the training set.

Comment: Without having data to reproduce the problem, I wouldn't be able to say.

Comment: I guess it means it is trying to classify all 10 test observation into `0` class

Comment: the problem is technically i put result1 as a numeric variable. it should return some numeric numbers instead of just 0 @abhiieor

Comment: Put all training data for prediction. See how results come. That may guide you better.